# pushViewController iphone not working

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

i am unable to get the pushViewController to work on a View Based Application on the iPhone. On my 'ProjectViewController' i have a IBAction with the following code :

```
-(IBAction)switchAugmented
{
    ARViewController *viewController = [[ARViewController alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    [viewController release];
}
```

When i run the program and press ibaction nothing happens. Besides that statement above do i need to do anything else to make the view appear? what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (...) on a View Based Application (...)

You just have no UINavController! Try to embed your main view in UINavigationController and everything will start working.

Answer (score 0):

Double check to make sure that the button you are pressing is connected to the right method in interface builder.  Also try putting an NSLog statement in the `switchAugmented` to see if the method is getting called.

You also have to check and see if you have a UINavigationController instance, otherwise you won't be able to push a new view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to push a new view controller in a View Based Project.  You need to create a Navigation Based Project or add an instance of the UINavigationController in your Main.nib (if your using a nib file) only then will the push view controller will work